# Get values from inputs then add them ,javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add values from n input field but i get result as NaN
Where am i going wrong

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input class="one" name="" value="1" type="text"></td> 
<td><input class="two" name=""  value="2"  type="text"></td> 
<td><input class="three" name=""  value="3"  type="text"></td> 
<td><input class="four" name=""  value="4"  type="text"></td> 
<td class="total"> </td>   
</tr>
</table>


<script>
var tdsOne =  document.getElementsByClassName("one").value;
var tdsTwo = document.getElementsByClassName("two").value;
var tdsThree =  document.getElementsByClassName("three").value;
var tdsFour = document.getElementsByClassName("four").value; 

var sum = 0;
sum += tdsOne + tdsTwo + tdsThree + tdsFour;

console.log(sum);    
document.getElementsByClassName('total')[0].textContent = sum;

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `document.getElementsByClassName` is an array-like object, you need to refer it by it's index

```
var tdsOne =  document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0].value;
var tdsTwo = document.getElementsByClassName("two")[0].value;
var tdsThree =  document.getElementsByClassName("three")[0].value;
var tdsFour = document.getElementsByClassName("four")[0].value;
```

**EDIT**

If you are looking for arithmetic addition , these values need to be converted to number. You can use [**Unary plus**](http://frontendplay.com/2013/05/25/plus-sign-javascript/) operator

```
sum += +tdsOne + +tdsTwo + +tdsThree + +tdsFour;
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/auvhppfr/)

Comment: What about sum the result, your solution comes to 1234

Comment: Also use Number() to be able to sum these results as

Number(document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0].value);

repeat for the subsequents values

Comment: @Fortune  out of curriosity what does the [0] stand for

Comment: @krushiovida Since getElementByClassName return a NodeList, you tell js that you want the first element, even if there's only a single one.

If you would have two element of class "one", and you would want the second element you would use :

document.getElementsByClassName("one")[1].value